# Add the names of the polygons all the time in Mapview R?

Tags: r, gis, mapview

I am using mapview in R to plot maps. I have more tha 100 polygons and I want to show them on the map with the names on it every time. But I couldn’t find a solution to this issue. Any idea?

```
mp<-st_read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgaitan/departamentos_argentina/master/departamentos-buenos_aires.json',stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
mapview(mp, zcol='cabecera')
```

[image: map photo]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean you want static labels that are always on the map, rather than just when you hover on them, you could use `addStaticLabels()` from {leafem}:

```r
library(leafem)
mp<-st_read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgaitan/departamentos_argentina/master/departamentos-buenos_aires.json',stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
mapview(mp, zcol='cabecera') %>%
  addStaticLabels(mp,
                  mp$cabecera,
                  noHide = TRUE,
                  textsize = "6px",
                  style = list("background-color" = "white", "font-weight" = "bold"))
```

which gives:

[image: Mapview with labels]